# Which jBoss to use AFTER 7.1.1.Final in production evironment?

Tags: jboss, licensing, jboss7.x, production-environment, jboss-eap-6

We're currently using jBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. Due to some bugs in this version we have to upgrade to a newer version.

Which one can we use?

What I realized is that jBoss EAP 6.1.0GA and 6.2.0GA are available but only allowed to use in development environment (without paying) not in prodcution.
I also read about jBoss AS 7.1.3.Final (aka EAP 6.0.1) which is much harder to find and you have to build manually.

As far as I understand it is only possible to build 7.1.3.Final manually and use this one. Am I right?
How about Wildfly?

Do we have to expect migration problems?

Answer (score 3):

As you have seen JBoss now comes in two (related) flavours; Community Releases and EAP. This is RedHat's attempt to have their cake and eat it. They say by paying for the licensing you are not paying for the product but are paying for the support and patches. But then they confuse things by only making certain versions available if you pay:

I believe you have three options

1) JBoss 7.1.2.Final and 7.1.3.Final do not exist as downloadable, binary, Community Releases. They do however exists as "tags" in the 7.1.2.Final and 7.1.3.Final [AS7 GitHub repository](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/tags).  So you can download these, build them yourself and use them (without paying in production). This minimises your migration issues, but you'd need to be happy building yourself

2) There is no downloadable, binary free 7.2 Final BUT that's what EAP 6.1.0 is based on. You do not need license/subscription to run the [Alpha version](http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/) in production and according to JBoss AS 7 lead, Jason Green EAP

> Alpha releases may be ran in production if you so desire. As to their
>   quality, 6.1.0.Alpha is of equivalent quality to a community final
>   release.

and

> A number of you have asked if community releases are usable in
>   production, and the answer is a definitive yes!

So why does it have that worrying 'Alpha' in its name

> the Alpha is where the extensive testing and hardening begins, so we
>   recommend GA or later for production if you are interested in using
>   EAP.

So if you're not happy doing that hardening yourself, this is not for you. There will also likely be bugs fixed in the EAP GA that are not in that Alpha.

Source: https://community.jboss.org/thread/228640?tstart=0

3) Go with [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/) which would be free to use wherever you want. But again this is a community version

The difference between Wildfly and AS7, is much smaller than AS7 and earlier versions, so hopefully your migrations issues should be limited.

As mentioned above, the community-supported versions can be deployed in production BUT you have to be happy with the difference from the supported versions and research them thoroughly. If you're not happy doing that, it may be a sign that a licensed version is required.

Comment: Red Hatter here.   This is not entirely true.  Depending on the situation, I would talk to Red Hat directly.

Comment: It's probably worth expanding that comment into a fuller answer - others may find the information useful

Comment: I can't talk in detail since you would need to have an NDA with Red Hat.

Comment: I would hope that Red Hat would be able to clarify any factual errors I'd made or explain any services or products they could offer, without a potential customer having an NDA in place first :-)

Comment: EAP can be used in production without paying, it's still GPL software and cannot have "only for production" restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

there is one important difference - WildFly is using undertow as webserver - JBoss AS uses Tomcat - keep this in mind when you think about migration...

Answer (score 1):

[WildFly](http://wildfly.org) is at version 8.1.0.Final and should be stable. You can [download](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) the latest version and try it.

The migration from JBoss AS 7.x to WildFly should be fairly painless.

Comment: Hm... Red Hatter here.   JBOSS EAP 7.X will not be based on Wildfly 8.